# Activity not found Excpetion in Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I have created a simple android application which opens other in-built activities like Contacts, Maps, Call, etc. Through my app, I can open contact and browser activity but whenever i try to open the call or map activity , the app crashes automatically.

Following is the code of my MainActivity.java

```
package com.suraj021.shortcuts;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;
    int request_code= 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //******** Call Button  *********//
        b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_btn);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,  
                                                           Uri.parse("+919999999999"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //********  Browser *********//
        b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.browser_btn);

        b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new  
          Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //********* Maps   ************//
        b4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.maps_btn);

        b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                                               Uri.parse("geo:37.827500,-122.481670"));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        //******* Contact Button *******//
        b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.contact_btn);

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                Intent i= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(i, request_code);

            }
        });


    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if (requestCode == this.request_code){
            if(resultCode== RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(this, data.getData().toString(),  
                                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() ;

                Intent i= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                                                  Uri.parse(data.getData().toString()));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
  }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is the code of my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button     android:id="@+id/call_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/call"/>

    <Button     android:id="@+id/contact_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/contact"/>

    <Button     android:id="@+id/browser_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/browser"/>

    <Button     android:id="@+id/maps_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/maps"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat is here:

01-15 13:50:00.605: W/dalvikvm(787): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
                                                             (group=0x40a71930)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No 
          Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DIAL
                                                                        dat=+919999999999 }
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at
             android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                    android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                             android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                             android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:840)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                      android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                      android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                         com.suraj021.shortcuts.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                           android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                      android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at
                                         android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native 
                                                                                Method)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                           java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
             com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at 
                                com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-15 13:50:00.635: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 13:50:02.525: I/Process(787): Sending signal. PID: 787 SIG: 9

here is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.suraj021.shortcuts"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Some intent's filters don't like empty uris ... so even if action is ok they will not eat 'em

Comment: please post the error log and your manifest.xml

Comment: even after providing uris , it crashes

Answer (score 0):

In Your code you are passing empty string to Uri.parse("") for call and map , therefore it is throwing NullPointerException.

change code to

```
//******** Call Button  *********//
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_btn);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("123456789")); //Your tel no
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and same for map. In Map also you have to pass non null value.